# Search and Filter Bootstrap Panels using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have lots(30+) of Bootstrap panels, which are as follows (each has a different title and content):

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have a search input

```
<input type="text" id="filter" placeholder="Filter Algorithms">
```

What I want to do it when someone types into the filter box it searches the title of the panels and filters them down as required. I have seen this done before, but I'm not quite sure where to start. This is the code I have so far:

```
$('#filter').keyup(function(){
    $('body').find('.panel-title').find($('#filter').val());
});
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "filters them down as required"? What's the expected behaviour?

Comment: Well, if a user enters `foo` in the input, it hides all panels that don't contain `foo` in the title. If they change it to `bar`, it shows all those with `bar` in the title etc.

Comment: Ok, the hiding functionality is what I was after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var $panels = $('.panel');

$('#filter').on('keyup', function() {
    var val = this.value.toLowerCase();

    $panels.show().filter(function() {
        var panelTitleText = $(this).find('.panel-title').text().toLowerCase();
        return panelTitleText.indexOf(val) < 0;
    }).hide();
});
```

**References**

1. `jQuery.filter()`: http://api.jquery.com/filter

Comment: When a user deletes the text is it possible to make it show it again? At the moment you have to reload the page to remove the search.

Comment: Perfect. Not to be a bother either, but it is possible to make it so that it isn't case sensitive?

Comment: @BenedictLewis I've updated the solution to add `.show()` before applying the filter. This code is a bit contrived (your panels will flash every time the `keyup` handler is run) but should give you what you need to get going.

Comment: @BenedictLewis I've added a couple of `toLowerCase()` calls to make the search case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

this jquery plugin could be useful:
https://github.com/Mixtags/jquery-filterbox

```
$('#list').filterbox({
        container: '.list-group',
        child: '.list-group-item',
        childKey: '.list-group-item > .title'
    });
```